# Would this Cron job be possible?

Tags: linux, cron

I am using Red Hat Linux 5 version and my application is a Java EE Application .

We allow users to upload the Pictures in our website . 
These Pictures will be stored inside a Folder in our server .

Now my question is that , on daily basis at a Particular time , i want to move all the images from that folder and move to another folder , where the folder name would be the day it has been moved .

Please let me know if this possible .

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, you can execute any shell script or application from a cron job, with any set of permissions. Can you write a script that does this? What difficulties have you come across?

Comment: Off topic for Stack Overflow - this is a Linux question, not a programming question. Voted to move to Super User.

Comment: There is such a thing as _documentation:_ `man crontab`, `man mv`, `man date`.

Answer (score 1):

```
man cron
man crontab
```

Write a small bashscript, which has your desired behaviour. Add it to your crontab or how cronjobs are realized in your distribution. (I'm using arch linux, so I do not want to give specific instructions, because of differences between distributions...)

Or use a java cron implementation and write everything in java.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a cron job to do so, as well as a shell script.

In cron:

```
# The first minute of the first hour of day run the script
1 1 * * * /scripts/move_images
```

---

In /scripts/move_image

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pick date (YYYY-MM-DD)
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

# Create new dir
mkdir -p /local_of_new_folder/$date

# Move all images from old folder to new folder
mv /old_folder/* /local_of_new_folder/$date
```

Change mode of the script to be a executable

```
chmod +x /scripts/move_image
```

Sorry about my English, i'm Brazilian
:)